# reCaptcha blocked frame (SOP?)

Tags: recaptcha, same-origin-policy

Got a Typo3 Installation where i've added Googles reCaptcha to a Form.

Did that already successful on other Typo3 installations, but this time, i get the blocked frame error in the Browser.

```
Blocked frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
  at um.f.hc (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/....)
```

This happens two times and after that, i get this massage in the frontend.

> Please upgrade to a supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.
>
> Alternatively if you think you are getting this page in error, please check your internet connection and reload.
>
> Why is this happening to me?

This is happening in all Browsers i checked (Chrome, FF, IE11).

To include the reCaptcha i've adde the following to the Template:

```
  <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var captchaCallback = function() { document.getElementById("captchaResponse").value = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value }
    var onSuccess = function(response) {
      var errorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-error");
      if (errorDivs.length) {
        errorDivs[0].className = "";
      }
      var errorMsgs = document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-error-message");
      if (errorMsgs.length) {
        errorMsgs[0].parentNode.removeChild(errorMsgs[0]);
      }
      captchaCallback();
      document.getElementById("fhcallback").submit();
    };
  </script>
  <input type="hidden" id="captchaResponse" name="fhcb[recaptcha]" value="" />
  <div id="recaptcha-demo" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[MYPUBLICKEY]" data-callback="onSuccess" data-bind="inp-submit"></div>
  <button class="orderButton bold" id="inp-submit" ###submit_nextStep###>Senden</button>
```

And in PHP:

```
$secret = '[MYSECRETKEY]';
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$apiResponse = json_decode(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getUrl($url.'?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$this->gp[$this->formFieldName]), true);
if($apiResponse['success'] == FALSE) {
    $checkFailed = $this->getCheckFailed();    
}
```

The Form is not visible on pageload. Its a slide in at the right side of the page, after clicking its toggle element.

I'am out of ideas and the client is bugging me already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue. On this Installation, the JavaScript Library **Mootools** was included.

After removing the include of Mootools, no further problems with blocked Frames occurred.